# Source a script in Linux for all users logging in that echo some things

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, startup, echo

We have CENTOS 7.x Linux with bash shell. I need a some environment variables to be set and some messages involving these env vars to be echoed (a banner kind of thing, but dynamic because it's got these env vars) for *all* users when they login or open an xterm/konsole. I've set this up in `/etc/profile.d/somescript.sh`

I see that when I log in, the env vars are indeed set, but the echoing doesn't happen. Why is that?

I see code in /etc/profile that reads like:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

Is it because of the output redirection above in the `else` branch? Or possibly some other script in the hierarchy of startup scripts that clear the screen? Or something else? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

If there is no reason to NOT use a motd banner, [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/459737/293440) from [Læti](https://serverfault.com/users/130516/l%c3%a6ti) might help you; namely:

---

`/etc/motd` is only read and not executed, so technically speaking, you cannot put shell commands in there.

However, it's possible to execute a shell script at login time that will have the same result.  This is usually achieved by adapting the `/etc/profile` script that is executed each time a user logs in.  A useful practice is to put the command you want to be executed in a script named `/etc/motd.sh` and call this script from `/etc/profile`, usually at about the end of it.

Comment: My bad. motd.sh works fine